# 0-999 Up - Down Counter with PIC16F877A

Tags: pic, microprocessors, proteus

i have a problem about microprocessor C programming.

[Hardware picture is here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cAVq.png)

I have to write a code on the C compiler, counting the 10^0 digit on the D port, the 10^1 digit on the C port, and the 10^2 digit on the B port for the given hardware. Also, the direction of counting with pin_a0 is regulated. If pin_a0 = 1 hardware will count forward, otherwise, count backwards.

I really appreciate any help, thank you so much

Comment: What have you written so far?  We can help you we can when you get stuck but we can't write the code for you.

Comment: Is your problem communicating with the panels or the counting itself?